# .net maf addin in transparent wpf window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, plugins, maf

I have a problem displaying MAF addin in a wpf transparent window.

If I set AllowsTransparency="False" the plugin is displayed and everything works fine. However AllowsTransparency="True" makes the plugin invisible, even though it is activate and initialized the same way it used to work in a non transparent window.

It is a requirement to make the window transparent, please help to find a workaround.

Note: Activating plugin either in the same AppDomain (as the main app window) or in a separate one doesn't make difference. However the idea is still to load it in a separate AppDomain under a restricted permission set, otherwise I wouldn't use MAF.

Comment: you can display MAF adding in different window. and make the main window transparent. until all the initialization take place in main window the MAD addin will be displayed on screen.

Comment: This is a good idea, however I'm looking for a better solution. I don't want to put the plugin that is 200x200px in a new window. And if I have 10 of such plugins? To put them all in a new window?

Comment: What is the UI of your addin, are you using a WindowsFormsHost?

Comment: No, I don't use WindowsFormsHost. It's a regular WPF UserControl.